# Windows Boot Manager Disapears after booting any Live Linux Distro?

Tags: windows, boot, multi-boot, troubleshooting

Anytime I plug in a USB to my computer and I boot it, I have to completely reinstall windows to even be able to get into it just after booting a USB. I don't even have to do anything in the Live Distro for it to cause this. Anyone know the issue? I boot windows off a 1 TB SSD, while I usually have Linux installed on a 256 GB SSD. Anyone know what's going on? I would be happy to give an additional information.

Comment: Sounds like you have a bugged/defected UEFI. Have you actually take a look at the UEFI boot order/menu to see how it looks like after you unplugged the USB and reboot? How exactly did you determine `WBM disappeared`?

Comment: Normally Windows has an identical copy of `/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` with the path of `/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi`, so even if the cached entry for the former is gone, you can still use the drive entry to load the latter.